# How to copy a few number of files using rsync

Tags: rsync

I have a few files which needs to be copied from source to destination.
the source has many files in it.
i want to know if its possible to use rsync to copy them (or if any other type of copier is available) and keep checking on the source for any changes made to them, for every few minutes.
(Only an example)Consider i am downloading a file from internet, a video file. I want to copy it to another location and keep it at the same location its being downloaded to.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You want to copy at another location while the file is still downloading?

Comment: Folder A has 50 files, I want to copy 25 files (from 25-50) and while they are being copied file number 49 and 50 are being downloaded. I have no idea how to copy files from 25-50 and how long it may take for the files to finish downloading, my internet is not stable.